# Variable result not what it should be

Tags: kotlin

I have these three implementations, that (should) do essentially the same: return the current position of Android exoplayer or 0 as integer.
But only nr. 1 works. Nr. 2 and nr.3 always return 0, even though `player` is instantiated. Is that expected behaviour?

1.

```
private var playbackPosition = 0
    get() {
        return if (player == null) 0 else player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000
    }
```

2.

```
private var playbackPosition = if (player == null) 0 else player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000
```

3.

```
private var playbackPosition = when(player)  {
    null -> 0
    else -> player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 are an implementation of a `get` function and invoked every time you access the variable.

Number 2 and 3 initialize a variable and the right side are only invoked once at creation time of the variable. Means the playback position is calculated only once.

The behavior works like designed. If you need the new position every time you access the variable you have to use an own getter function.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the question, I assume you're not that familiar with Kotlin and/or Java, so I'm going to explain the difference between the two.

First of all, you need to understand the difference between a function and a variable/constant. A function can have a varying result when it's called (assuming it's not a `void`/`Unit`), but a variable has a fixed result until it's updated. Take this:

```
var toggle = Random().nextBoolean()
var dependent = if(toggle) 0 else 1
toggle = !toggle
```

If you print the variable before and after the toggle is switched, the variable will not change. When it's been assigned, it stays with that value until something updates it. So if you add print statements, it will be the same. Let's expand on that:

```
var toggle: Boolean = Random().nextBoolean()

fun someFunction() : Int = (if(toggle) 0 else 1).also { toggle = !toggle }
```

The `also` block here is an extension function that lets you do stuff, but still return the variable it's called on. Here, either 1 or 0 is returned, and the toggle is inverted. If you call this two times, you'll see a different result. This is because you get a different value based on a condition. Again, you see the value doesn't change even though the toggle does.

**TL;DR:** Variables have a given value until changed. Methods returning values can change based on conditions, because it's updated every time it's called.

Now, what does this mean for your code?

First of all, for the first snippet, you should use `val` instead. Kotlin is really nice like that; if you override the getter of a val, you don't need to initialize it. It's called backing fields.

Anyways, this:

```
private val playbackPosition
    get() {
        return if (player == null) 0 else player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000
    }
```

returns a value depending on the player variable *when it is called*. Where as the other examples:

```
private var playbackPosition = if (player == null) 0 else player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000


private var playbackPosition = when(player)  {
    null -> 0
    else -> player?.currentPosition?.toInt() as Int / 1000
}
```

Set the value when they're defined. You could change those to a `val` too; they aren't automatically re-assigned.

Initial assignment, that being the code you have there, is only run once, and that's when the class is initialized. If the variable is inside a method, the variable is initialized when the method is called. `lateinit` vars can be set at a later time, but initial assignment is only run once. For any changes you'll need to update it.

However, this is where methods come in handy. Depending on what you have, you could also create a backing field, a "cache" in a way. This isn't necessary unless object creation is heavy. You don't need to worry about this for something as simple as integers. Using a method that returns the value (in your case, the getter), is kinda like doing this:

```
var x: Int = updateValue()

fun updateValue() : Int = if ... // alternatively does x = instead of returning an int

...
x = updateValue()
x.let { foo bar }
```

Although that is a considerably harder way of doing stuff.

---

> But only Nr. 1 works. Nr. 2 and Nr.3 always return 0, although player is instantiated.

If you get `0` all the time for 2 and 3, that means `player == null` *when the variables were intiailized*, but it wasn't null when the getter for the first example was called.

> Is that expected behaivour?

Considering the code, yes. It's by design.

**TL;DR:** Again, variables aren't automatically updated when a creating condition (i.e. player == null) changes. You'll either need to manually update it, or use methods over variables.